# Record is not updating in a phonegap sqlite storage given in a particular query

Tags: sqlite, cordova, updates

This is the query which is update single record in a table.
Where FriendTable.tablename and other column name is define a constant file.
Values which is to update is store in Friend variable.

```
FriendTable.updateValues=function(Friend,successCallback,errorCallback){
    var query = 'update '+ FriendTable.tablename + ' set ' + FriendTable.lat + '=?,' + FriendTable.lon + '=?,' + FriendTable.locaddr + '=?,' + FriendTable.locts + '=? where ' + FriendTable.phonenumber + " =?";
    app.dbobj.transaction(function (tx) {
        console.log('Update Friend record :: ' + query);
        console.log('Friend data :: ' + Friend.toString());
        tx.executeSql(query,[Friend.lat,Friend.lon,Friend.locaddr,Friend.locts,Friend.phonenumber],successCallback,errorCallback);
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried to wrap ? with ' like: update mytable set attribut = '?' where id = '?'

Comment: So you have to wrap only string-attributs with ' like: FriendTable.locaddr + "='?',"